# how to use robot framework for value validation?

Tags: python, robotframework

New to the world of robot framework. I have written a ppython program to compare the values of three comulns of a CSV file using pandas. So far so good. The program runs successfully. However, I need to use robot framework to create the test cases and show the results as pass or fail. Below is the python program:

```
import pandas as pd

# Reading the CSV file

df = pd.read_csv(r'xl1.csv', skipinitialspace=True, sep=',')

# Summation pf the two columns and giving results

sum1 = df['Gross_Salary'].sum()
sum2 = df['Deduction'].sum()
diff = sum1 - sum2

if diff == df['Net_Salary'].sum():
    print("Pass")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

The above code is reading a CSV file, and adding two columns, and then compare the value with the 3rd column. If they match, then "pass", otherwise "fail"

### CSV File:

```
Gross_Salary Deduction Net_Salary
100             20         80
2000            200       1500
300             0          300
```

Below is the Robot code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     Process
Library     BuiltIn

*** Test Cases ***
PandaTest
    ${result}=      run process     python  <path_to_xl_parse.py>
    BuiltIn.Should Be Equal As Strings       ${result.rc}  PASS
```

I am getting below error:

```
PandaTest                                                             | FAIL |
2 != PASS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pan                                                                   | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Please help,
Thank you

Comment: what is **all** in `df['Net_Salary'].sum().all` ?

Comment: When I am not using "all", I was getting error. However, now I see that with sum(), the error is gone. So it can be ignored, and removing from the main post as well

Comment: Look at your `csv` file second row, `Net_Salary + Deduction != Gross_Salary`. You can list the rows where this fails with `df[~(df['Net_Salary'] == (df['Gross_Salary] - df['Deduction']))]`

Comment: I really don't understand what changes you want me to make in both the codes

Comment: **There is nothing wrong with your code and you have issues in your test data.** In the sample data, the logic `Net_Salary = Gross_Salary - Deduction` fails for second row. You need to correct your test data. You can use the code from the above comment to list the rows where this fails.

Answer (score 0):

"Pass" is not equal to "PASS". You should use identical strings in both codes.

And use

```
Log    ${result}
```

to see what you get from script in first place. Printing values is always a good idea when searching for an error.